# Hair particles is less when rendered

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I am having trouble with making the hair particles, when rendered it does not seem to render all the hair that is visible in viewport:[image]

When rendered image:

[image]

Would converting it to mesh help?

Comment: Check that  the scale of the hair is not too small.Because if it is too small the hair will be very thin and will not be visible clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because on the end, by default, hair is tinnier.

[image]

Look at hair settings:

[image]

It is 1.0 thickness at root, and 0.1 at end of the hair. Tune this settings.

Also, look at shape setting, it setups how thickness distribute along hair length:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, you helped me avoid a lot of trouble! :)